# Why are CSS box-sizing content-box vs border-box so different?

Tags: html, css

In the example below I changed only the CSS box-sizing from content-box to border-box. The output difference is huge. Try this code:

```css
.div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.div2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS box-sizing content-box vs border-box</h1>
<div class="div1">box-sizing: content-box</div>
<br>
<div class="div2">box-sizing: border-box</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

From [thisthat.dev](https://thisthat.dev/border-box-vs-content-box/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20content%20box%20model,same%20dimension%20as%20the%20element.&text=In%20the%20border%20box%20model,padding%20from%20the%20element%27s%20dimension.): "In the content box model, the content inside of element will have the same dimension as the element. In the border box model, the content's dimension has to subtract the border and padding from the element's dimension."